# Emulate the Linux console

Tags: linux, tty, console

Is there a way of emulating the Linux virtual console inside X?
I. e. an environment where `/dev/tty` for all practical
purposes (`ioctl_console(2)`) acts exactly as the Linux console
would but that runs as an X client and can be fired up at will
and allows screenshots?

I want to avoid having to resort to QEMU if possible.

(Note that a terminal emulator will no do as it does not support
the required `ioctl()`s.)

Background:
I’m programming against the virtual console and need a more
efficient (and possibly automatable) approach to testing.

Comment: What exactly do which terminal emulators not support?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: “What exactly do which terminal emulators not support?” — the ioctls I gave. E. g. ``int main(){char c; assert(ioctl (0, KDGETLED, &c) == 0); }``.

Answer (score 1):

No.

While you could emulate any ioctl()s you want with [`cuse`](https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/), that's not enough to implement a terminal like `/dev/tty1` is -- whose interface also includes job control (i.e. correctly forwarding signals like `SIGHUP` or `SIGTTIN` to processes), not just some extra ioctl()s.

Notice that you can make a snapshot of real linux "console" has via the `/dev/vcsX` and `/dev/vcsaX` (text mode) or `/dev/fbX` (framebuffer), so reimplementing it sounds pretty pointless -- just like targetting the linux console in particular, which is not even guaranteed to exist even on Linux systems (and in fact it does not exists on 99.9% of Linux systems ;-))

Comment: I hadn’t heard about CUSE, thanks for the pointer. Very intriguing, but it’d also mean that I have to implement the kernel side of things. Unlikely to happen today. ;)

Comment: “Notice that you can make a snapshot of real linux "console"” — oh yeah, definitely. Still to actually run test code on that console I’d have to deal with getty. Which would be a pain to automate and probably requires privileged access. Booting a VM is probably the simpler approach.

Comment: “And in fact it does not exists on 99.9% of Linux systems” — granted, though it exists on 100 % of systems I care for. ;)